# Bootstrap progress bar - can't recreate with my own code

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried to create vertical progress bars with bootstrap3 on JsFiddle and got this:

[The result I'm looking for](https://jsfiddle.net/7tgh988z/148/)

If I copy all this code into my files and run it then the progressbars are not split in the middle horizontally but instead they are split vertically.

How can I achieve the same result? Am I missing someyhing here?

Here is the code for my stylesheet:

```
.container { margin-top: 10px; }

.progress {
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 5px;

    position: relative;
}

.vertical .progress-bar {
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3 ease;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease;
    transition: height 0.3s ease;

    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
}

.progress .vertical {
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.vertical .progress-bar-label{
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: without inspect the code with the issue is difficult, i think in your code there must be a class that override your style of div.progress-bar

Comment: So it seems even my example is not what I am looking for. When you decrease the percentages so they are not adding up to 100% it is revealed that the bar starts from the top instead of the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I got it working with flipping the resulting progressbar and then flipping the contained span element again. Also I got this text centering figured out which also uses transforms.

The result can be seen here: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7tgh988z/159/)

As jsfiddle links require some code, here is the transform that solved my problems:

```
transform-origin: center;
transform: scaleY(-1);
```

Use this within your `progress` and `progress-bar-label` styles if you need a vertically stacked bottom to top progressbar. Without this your progressbar will go from top to bottom.